# How can we allocate memory for varchar query cache plan for only certain length unlike defaulting to max (8000)?

Tags: mysql, performance, spring-data-jpa, sql-execution-plan

We have simple entity class with `String` and when we look at the query cache plan for the query which is using the corresponding field, the maximum length is being allocated to for the same underneath.

Is there some way to let underneath platform know to allocate only certain memory?

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54417765) link suggested to use `@Size` and `@Valiadate` for the same purpose, but it did not work.

We are using following entity:

```
@Entity 
public class Product{
   @Id 
   private Integer id; 

  @Column(name = "number")
   private String number; 

}
```

The query is any standard `jpql find by` query

```
@Validate
public interface FooJpaRepository extends JpaRepository<Foo, Integer> {

    List<Foo> findByNumber(@Size(max = 16) String number);
}
```

And execution plan result, after adding @size and @Validate as suggested by another answer:

```
DECLARE @P0 varchar(8000); select product0_.id as product_id1_1_, product0_.NAME as name2_1_,
from p.[Product] product0_ where product0_.name=@P0
```

---